# How can I get the input to prompt the user for two characters and use them for swapping?

Tags: c, sorting, loops, pointers

I am making a small application in ANSI C using GCC in Ubuntu. The application is supposed to decipher a message by swapping two letters within an Array.

My main class:

```
#include "CipherCode.h"

char cipherText[] = "PUCXHTULUL, XW AELW, JUAJ TXJ FOCTXWU EH XW OCCQLPOWCU RXAT ATU DUZ GXJA. RTUW ATU FUJJOBU XJ LUCUXIUP, TU JUAJ ATU DUZ RTUUGJ AQ ATU";

int main(void) {
    char ch = 0;
    char chLetter, chReplacement;

    char *pLetter = chLetter;
    char *pReplacement = chReplacement;

    int cipherStats[ALPHABET_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char chAlphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int *pCipherStats = cipherStats; 
    char *pCipherText = cipherText;
    char *pAlphabet = chAlphabet;

    do {
        DisplayCipherText(pCipherText);
        GetFrequency(pCipherText, pCipherStats);
        DisplayCipherStats(pCipherStats, pAlphabet, 26);
        chLetter = GetLetter("Enter character to substitute:");
        chReplacement = GetLetter("Swap this with character:");
        Decipher(pCipherText, pReplacement);
        printf("%s", "\nPress 'n' to exit or any other key to continue...\n"); /* prompt to continue looping */
    } while ((ch = getchar()) != 'n'); /* loop unless user enters char 'n' */

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My CipherCode.c file:

```
#include "CipherCode.h"

char GetLetter(const char* prompt) {
    char ch = '\0';
    do {
        printf( "%s", prompt ); 
        fflush(stdout);
        ch = toupper(getchar());
        printf( "%c\n", ch );
    } while (!isalpha(ch));
    return ch;
}

int GetFrequency(const char *pCipherText, int *pCipherStats) {
    printf("Frequency analysis:\n");
    for (; *pCipherText != '\0'; pCipherText++) {
        if (isalpha(*pCipherText)) {
            int index = toupper(*pCipherText) - 'A';
            if ( index >= 0 && index < 26 ) {
                pCipherStats[index]++;
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "%c gives invalid index: %d\n", *pCipherText, index);
            }
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void DisplayCipherText(char *pCipherText) {
    for (; *pCipherText != '\0'; pCipherText++) {
        printf("%c", *pCipherText);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

void DisplayCipherStats(int *pCipherStats, char *pAlphabet, int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { /*for each letter in the alphabet*/
        printf("%1c:%-4d", *pAlphabet++, *pCipherStats++); /*print frequency information*/
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

void Decipher(char *pCipherText, char *pReplacement) {
    for (; *pCipherText != '\0'; pCipherText++) {
        if (*pCipherText == *pReplacement) {
            SortChar(pCipherText, pReplacement);
        }
    }
}

void BubbleSort(int *pInt, char *pCh) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = ALPHABET_SIZE-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (*(pInt+j) < *(pInt+j+1)) {
                SortChar(pCh+j, pCh+j+1);
                SortInt(pInt+j, pInt+j+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

void SortInt(int *pIntA, int *pIntB) {
    int tempInt; /*temp variable*/
    tempInt = *pIntA; /*store old value before it is overwritten*/
    *pIntA = *pIntB; /*overwrite old value*/
    *pIntB = tempInt; /*complete the swap*/
}

void SortChar(char *pChA, char *pChB) {
    char tempCh; /*temp variable*/
    tempCh = *pChA; /*store old value before it is overwritten*/
    *pChA = *pChB; /*overwrite old value*/
    *pChB = tempCh; /*complete the swap*/
}
```

My header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26

/*
* global variables
*/
extern char cipherText[];

/*
* function prototypes
*/
char GetLetter(const char*);
int GetFrequency(const char*, int*);
void DisplayCipherText(char*);
void DisplayCipherStats(int*, char*, int);
void Decipher(char*, char*);
void BubbleSort(int*, char*);
void SortInt(int*, int*);
void SortChar(char*, char*);
```

I would like the program to take chLetter and replace all occurrences of chLetter in cipherText with chReplacement. For each iteration of the do loop, I want to display cipherText, then analyze the frequency of letters in cipherText, then display the frequencies, then ask for chLetter, then ask for chReplacement, and lastly swap chLetter with chReplacement.

The program must use pointers to reference the content of arrays. I also must use my sort functions to decipher the text.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `char chAlphabet[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {'A','B','C','D','E',',...` is ugly, you could generate this with a small loop.

Comment: Exactly!
`char chAlphabet
[ALPHABET_SIZE];`
`for(i=0; i<26; i++) chAlphabet[i]=65+i;`

Comment: or just `char chAlphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`, the excess \0 doesn't hurt much and could even be helpful…

Comment: Inside the `GetFrequency` function, for the case when the *current character* from the string `pCipherText` being something non-alphabetic, `pCipherStats[-1]` is being attempted to get incremented. As far as I know, it is not a valid operation. I would recommend using an `if ( isalpha( ch ) ) pCipherStats[ch - 'A']++;` for both the ternary assignment line and the line-in-question.

Comment: `scanf` does _not_ return a `char*`

Comment: @rmartinjak Rather `char chAlphabet[26] = "ABCD...";` for the exact same outcome, with no 26th element of zero, but that doesn't look too much different from what OP already has...

Comment: @ThoAppelsin it sure does, it's only around 1/3 of the characters. And it is the most portable solution because C does _not_ guarantee that `'A'` to `'Z'` are consecutive values.

Comment: @rmartinjak I don't think that would ever be a real concern. If there really is a valid case where letters from `A` to `Z` do not have consecutive numeric representation, then this programme wouldn't be portable no matter which one is used, because of the current implementation of the `GetFrequency` function.

Comment: I have modified `chAlphabet` with a format change and changed `GetFrequency()` to prevent a `-1` index. I am still having issues with `GetLetter()` and `GetReplacement()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char GetLetter(char chLetter) {
    char *pLetter = scanf("Enter character to substitute: %c", &chLetter);
    return *pLetter;
}
```

^ wrong way of specifying a scanf format string, the format string is used to 
match input from the buffer not for displaying a prompt. scanf returns number
of arguments that it found from the buffer not a char*

instead do something like this:

```
char GetLetter() 
{
  printf( "%s", "Enter character to substitute:"); 
  fflush(stdout);
  return getchar();
}
```

or to make it more flexible specify the prompt in the argument:

```
char GetLetter(const char* prompt) 
{
  printf( "%s", prompt ); 
  fflush(stdout);
  return getchar();
}
```

then you can call it with

```
char chReplace = GetLetter("Enter character to substitute:");
char chWith = GetLetter("Swap this with character:");
```

with this function

```
int GetFrequency(char *pCipherText, int *pCipherStats) {
printf("Frequency analysis:\n");
for (; *pCipherText != '\0'; pCipherText++) { /*check if at the end of the array*/
    char ch = *pCipherText; /*store current letter as a char*/
    if (isalpha(ch)) pCipherStats[ch - 'A']++; /*if character is a letter, store ascii value in array and increment array*/
}
```

^ you seem to assume that all input letters are in upper case, maybe you should make sure of that by converting the character to upper case first. Always good to better be safe than sorry when programming. Normally it is not good style to modify the arguments by using them as temporary variables, when the function is more complex it can make the code confusing. Instead use a local var e.g.

```
int GetFrequency(const char *pCipherText, int *pCipherStats) 
{
  char* p = pCiperText;
  printf("Frequency analysis:\n");
  for (; *p != '\0'; ++p) 
  {
    if (isalpha(*p)) 
    {
      int index = toupper(*p) - 'A';
      if ( index >= 0 && index < 26 )
      {
        pCipherStats[index]++;
      }
      else
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "%c gives invalid index: %d\n", *p, index );
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

that said, you could make the GetLetter function even more robust:

```
char GetLetter(const char* prompt) 
{
  char ch = '\0';
  do
  {
    printf( "%s", prompt ); 
    fflush(stdout);
    ch = toupper(getchar());
    printf( "%c\n", ch );
  }
  while ( !isalpha(ch) );
  return ch;
}
```

Comment: How does this get any input? I thought `scanf()` was how to get input from the user?

Answer (score 0):

`GetLetter()` and `GetReplacement()` have multiple issues.

The first line defines it as a function taking a `char` and returning a `char`.
This is actually okay, but since you don't *use the passed value*  in
`chLetter`, you don't need to pass it at all.

```
char GetLetter(char chLetter) {
```

This line does *not* do what you think it does. It will *not* use the text
`"Enter the character ..."` as a prompt, but try to match the input to it. This
means the only way that `scanf` wouldn't fail would be that the user *types the
whole string*, which is clearly not what you want.
`scanf` does also *not* return a `char *`, but an `int`, indicating how many
input items were successfully matched or `EOF` in case the end of input was
reached or an error occured before matching the first item. Assigning an `int`
value to a pointer is usually meaningless

```
char *pLetter = scanf("Enter character to substitute: %c", &chLetter);
```

Here you're trying to dereference a pointer that does not point to a valid
memory location.

```
return *pLetter;
}
```

A simple implementation could be:

```
/** Prompt for inputting a single character
 *
 * Reads the first character and then discards the rest of the line.
 * The `text` parameter is the prompt string.
 * Returns an int so we can indicate EOF, which isn't representable by char
 */
int prompt_char(const char *text) {
    int c, tmp;
    printf("%s: ", text);
    c = getchar();
    do {
        tmp = getchar();
    } while (tmp != '\n' && tmp != EOF);
    return c;
}
```

Which you can use from your `main()` like this:

```
do {
    ...
    chLetter = prompt_char("Enter character to substitute");
    chReplacement = prompt_char("Swap this with character");
            if (chLetter == EOF || chReplacement == EOF) {
                // do something, e.g. break from the loop or exit the program
            }
    ...
} while (...)
```